# R: A way to filter based on values in another table?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, multi-table

I have two tables that have the following structures. Table 1, which I will call the Summary Table, is a list of category-values with a count:

| Category | Value | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat1 | Val1 |  |
| Cat1 | Val2 |  |
| Cat1 | Val3 |  |
| Cat2 | Val1 |  |
| Cat2 | Val2 |  |
| Cat3 | Val1 |  |
| Cat3 | Val2 |  |

```
summary <- data.frame(Category = c('Cat1', 'Cat1', 'Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat3'),
                      Value = c('Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val1', 'Val2'),
                      Count = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

I want to populate this table with counts gathered from Table 2, which we will call Raw Data Table, which has the following structure:

| Entity | Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ent1 | Val1 | Val1 | Val2 |
| Ent2 | Val1 | Val1 | Val2 |
| Ent3 | Val2 | Val2 | Val1 |
| Ent4 | Val2 | Val1 | Val2 |
| Ent5 | Val3 | Val1 | Val2 |
| Ent6 | Val3 | Val1 | Val1 |
| Ent7 | Val3 | Val2 | Val2 |

```
rawdata <- data.frame(Entity = c('Ent1', 'Ent2', 'Ent3', 'Ent4', 'Ent5', 'Ent6', 'Ent7'),
                      Cat1 = c('Val1', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val3', 'Val3'),
                      Cat2 = c('Val1', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val1', 'Val1', 'Val1', 'Val2'),
                      Cat3 = c('Val2', 'Val2', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val2', 'Val1', 'Val2'))
```

I want to populate the "Count" column from the summary table with the appropriate counts for each category & value pair. Programmatically, what I would want to do would be to have a counter, go through the Raw Data Table and just update the count for each value. I think this would be very inefficient in R. What I thought I would do is filter for the values but because column names are not evaluated as variables, I am at a loss of how to do this.

What I have tried (and I what I think I want something like is):

```
library(dplyr)
summary$Count <- nrow(rawdata %>% filter(get(summary$Category) == get(summary$Value)))
```

This isn't working, however. How do I get the filter to take values from another table?

Answer (score 1):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and use `count` to get the frequency count

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rawdata %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Entity, names_to = "Category", values_to = "Value") %>% 
  count(Category, Value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  Category Value     n
#  <chr>    <chr> <int>
#1 Cat1     Val1      2
#2 Cat1     Val2      2
#3 Cat1     Val3      3
#4 Cat2     Val1      5
#5 Cat2     Val2      2
#6 Cat3     Val1      2
#7 Cat3     Val2      5
```

NOTE: `pivot_longer` reshapes the data from the 'wide' format to 'long' format.  By specifying the `cols = -Entity`, it is converting the rest of the columns to 'long' format with the column name as "Category" specified by `names_to` and the corresponding values as "Value" (`values_to`)

---

Or using `base R` with `table`

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(data.frame(Category =
   names(rawdata)[-1][col(rawdata[-1])], 
        Value = unlist(rawdata[-1])))), Freq  > 0)
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what pivot_longer is actually doing?